# transform/reshaping data for analyzing - Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm on a mission where I have to extract information from the web (IMDB-Oscar-winning movies) and then analyze the data.

I use Python libraries (Requests, Pandas) on jupyter

As of this moment, I've already pulled the data from the site 
And the data is stored in a list within a list as in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKWQx.png).

My question is, how do I change the shape so that I will be more comfortable analyzing the data?I would be happy to receive the data in a tabular structure 
but the length of the lists is not identical.

Comment: Can you post sample data? (Not an image)

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the list of lists into a dictionary and then use an object db like MongoDB or just store as json for further analysis.

```
myList = [[('Name', 'Moonlight'), ('Genres', ['Drama']),
           ('Writers', ['Barry Jenkins', 'Tarell Alvin McCraney']),
           ('Actors', ['Mahershala Ali', 'Shariff Earp', 'Duan Sanderson']),
           ('Directors', ['Barry Jenkins']), ('Duration', '1h 51min')]]
l = [tup for item in myList for tup in item]
d = {col: attr for col, attr in l}
print(d)
>>{'Genres': ['Drama'], 'Name': 'Moonlight', 'Directors': ['Barry Jenkins'], 'Writers': ['Barry Jenkins', 'Tarell Alvin McCraney'], 'Actors': ['Mahershala Ali', 'Shariff Earp', 'Duan Sanderson'], 'Duration': '1h 51min'}
```

If you want your data to be tabular you'll want to visualize the tables two-dimensionally like an RDBMS with primary/foreign key relationships because storing lists in columns in Pandas doesn't really work well.

```
movie (mov_id*, name, duration)
directors (mov_id*, director_name)
writers (mov_id*, writer_name)
actors (mov_id*, actor_name)
```

You'll have four DataFrames from this schema (some table optimization might yield less tables), of which you can do relational algebra on using Pandas to get the work you need done.